# AsyncImageView crashes on new iPad Air

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios7, uiimage

Good morning,

I recently just got a new iPad Air and my app for some reason keeps crashing, ONLY on that device. I have a weird feeling about this. It runs fine on the 64-bit simulator, which I thought was the problem. I am currently using AsyncImageView https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView within a UITableView Cell. This has never happened to me before, but now I keep getting:

```
Incident Identifier: 363B4423-1A21-4104-8067-0EDFFFFF7248
CrashReporter Key:   2fd30a27b8ab4d0d360bedb48cdda187c2ee2242
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/848571DF-F961-4B38-BA25-C86E6D0BC36D/XXXXX.app/XXXXX
Identifier:          com.leclerc.XXXXX
Version:             0.0.0.6 (0.0.0.6)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-11-12 16:45:47.036 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.3 (11B511)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000100001da0
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193dd5548 objc_retain + 24
1   XXXXX                           0x000000010012c48c -[AsyncImageView setImage:] (AsyncImageView.m:691)
2   XXXXX                           0x0000000100129fb4 -[AsyncImageLoader imageLoaded:] (AsyncImageView.m:399)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187a576d8 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001879a4018 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
5   Foundation                      0x000000018852ea14 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
6   XXXXX                           0x0000000100128390 -[AsyncImageConnection cacheImage:] (AsyncImageView.m:164)
7   Foundation                      0x000000018861c92c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 324
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187a63778 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187a62ad4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 252
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187a60d6c __CFRunLoopRun + 628
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001879a1b34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018d37382c GSEventRunModal + 164
13  UIKit                           0x000000018a9e00e4 UIApplicationMain + 1152
14  XXXXX                           0x00000001000f6eb0 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001943c3a9c start + 0
```

it crashes at this piece of code:

```
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    super.imageURL = imageURL;
    if (_showActivityIndicator && !self.image && imageURL)
    {
        if (_activityView == nil)
        {
            _activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:_activityIndicatorStyle];
            _activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
            _activityView.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
            _activityView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
            [self addSubview:_activityView];
        }
        [_activityView startAnimating];
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in that code and step through to see which line is causing the crash? I guess it's messaging a released object, try with zombies

Comment: is it possible imageURL == super.imageURL?

Comment: I'm thinking about switching to SDWebImage... what do you think?

Comment: never used it... can't you just use `[ UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:... ]` etc

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same crash on iPhone 5S.
Updating AsyncImage to version 1.5.1 solved it for me.
Get it from here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: Updating asyncimage is not solving the solution

Comment: I'm also getting same error on both iPhone 5S and iPad air. but other devices running well my application. Now I have switched on SDWebImage. That's too good . Thanks a lot..

Comment: My app was crashing on iPhone 5s. Replacing new library it works for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried version 1.5.1 too, but no use. You have to set your deployment target of your application maximum to 5.1.1, else this library will crash in anyway.